# How to make the right connection with mongo URI with pymongo?

Tags: mongodb

I don’t know how to connect mongodbs by URI correctly with pymongo (version>3). Two types of script list as followed, the type B can run .find() correctly, but the type A can’t. How to modify the codes in type A to work?

type A:

```
uri = "mongodb://{}:{}@{}:{}".format(username, password, host, port)
for k in ["A","B","C"]:
    exec "{}_uri = '{}/{}_{}'".format(k, uri, k, envname)
    exec "db_{} = MongoClient({}_uri)".format(k, k)
```

type B:

```
connection = MongoClient(host, port)
for k in ["A","B","C"]:
    exec "db_{} = connection.{}_{}".format(k, k, envname)
    exec "db_{}.authenticate(username, password)".format(k)
```

Comment: why are you using `exec`?

Comment: https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/authentication.html

Comment: @user3100115 Thank you. The dbs share the same username and password. I am a greenhand to python, how to write it better?

Comment: @JST  Thank you, the type B is from the official links, maybe `client.the_database.authenticate('user', 'password')` is required? the `user` and `password` have set in the uri yet.